# VB.net RSA importing private key from text file.

Tags: vb.net, import, rsa, pem

Basically im encrypting a message in PHP using openssl. I have already generated a valid key pair (both saved to PEM files).

In vb.net im trying to use the private key to decrypt the message saved in the mysql database, but i cant seem to find a way to incorporate the private key into the decryption examples. All the examples i have found all concentrate on generating a key pair.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The closest ive come so far is with the FromXmlString, but it throws up and invalid syntax. Anyone know the expected schema? Thanks

Comment: Solved!!!  If anyone is interested, I opted for a different approach. Instead of using a PEM file, i converted the PEM file to an XML file (i think its an PKCS #8 file) using this tool [link](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/). I then used the fromxmlstring to load my private key. Worked a charm!